# AWS Lambda - Only getting answer after the second test trigger

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios

I'm developing an AWS Lambda in TypeScript that uses Axios to get data from an API and that data will be filtered and be put into a dynamoDb.

The code looks as follows:

```
export {};
const axios = require("axios");
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event: any) => {
    const shuttleDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const startDate = "2021-08-16";
    const endDate = "2021-08-16";
    const startTime = "16:00:00";
    const endTime = "17:00:00";

    const response = await axios.post('URL', {
        data:{
            "von": startDate+"T"+startTime,
            "bis": endDate+"T"+endTime
        }}, {
            headers: {
            'x-rs-api-key': KEY
            }
        }
    );
    const params = response.data.data;
    const putPromise = params.map(async(elem: object) => {
        
        delete elem.feat1;
        delete elem.feat2;
        delete elem.feat3;
        delete elem.feat4;
        delete elem.feat5;
        
        const paramsDynamoDB = {
            TableName: String(process.env.TABLE_NAME),
            Item: elem
        }
        shuttleDB.put(paramsDynamoDB).promise();
    });
    await Promise.all(putPromise);
};
```

This all works kind of fine. If the test button gets pushed the first time, everything seems fine and is working. E.g. I received all the `console.log`s during developing but the **data is not put into the db**.

With the second try it is the same output but the data is successfully put into the Db.

Any ideas regarding this issue? How can I solve this problem and have the data put into the Db after the first try?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to return the promise from the db call -

```
return shuttleDB.put(paramsDynamoDB).promise();
```

also, `Promise.all` will complete early if any call fails (compared to Promise.allSettled), so it may be worth logging out any errors that may be happening too.

Better still, take a look at transactWrite - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#transactWrite-property to ensure all or nothing gets written

Comment: From your Link : "Synchronous write operation that groups up to 25 action requests" 
So if my request gets me 25+ elements this will be a problem right? Because that can be the case...
I'll add the error logging. Thanks for the headsup!

Comment: unfortunately yes, it only deals with up to 25 items, though if you are starting to write large batches, I would suggest involving something like an SQS queue for funnelling items into the database rather than flooding items at the database